# Bind Server config is sub-optimal. DNS is intermittent at best

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, bind

My Bind Server configuration works .. Just not very well and I am not sure what the underlying cause is, or where to fix it.

I have a DNS dedicated server.  `ns1.ywpadmin.com`.  It's public IP address is `40.142.31.33` and internal ip address is `10.0.0.200`

My web server is located at `40.142.31.34`.

The website I am testing is `roofrightroofing.net`

Now when I go to `whatsmydns.net` Only about half of the servers worldwide show up with the green check mark.

When I run `dig roofrightroofing.net SOA @localhost` from the DNS server -- I get (keep in mind I haven't set up the NS2 server yet.  I want my config functional before that happens):

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40310
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;roofrightroofing.net.      IN  SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
roofrightroofing.net.   38400   IN  SOA ns1.ywpadmin.com. admin.ywpadmin.com. 1494612100 10800 3600 604800 38400

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
roofrightroofing.net.   38400   IN  NS  ns1.ywpadmin.com.
roofrightroofing.net.   38400   IN  NS  ns2.ywpadmin.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.ywpadmin.com.   38400   IN  A   10.0.0.200
ns2.ywpadmin.com.   38400   IN  A   10.0.0.200

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 21 14:30:03 CST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 181
```

Here is the configuration for my bind server:

**named.conf.options**

```
options {

    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    recursion no;
    version "Not Disclosed";

};
```

**named.conf.local**

```
//roofrightroofing.net--
zone "roofrightroofing.net" {
         type master;
         file "/var/lib/bind/roofrightroofing.net.hosts";
         };
//--roofrightroofing.net
```

**roofrightroofing.net.hosts**

```
$ttl 38400
roofrightroofing.net.                       IN          SOA      ns1.ywpadmin.com. admin.ywpadmin.com. (
                            1494612100
                            10800
                            3600
                            604800
                            38400 )
roofrightroofing.net.                       IN       NS      ns1.ywpadmin.com.
roofrightroofing.net.                       IN       NS      ns2.ywpadmin.com.
roofrightroofing.net.                       IN       A       40.142.31.34
www.roofrightroofing.net.                   IN       A       40.142.31.34
```

**ywpadmin.com.hosts**

```
$ttl 38400
ywpadmin.com.                       IN          SOA      ns1.ywpadmin.com. admin.ywpadmin.com. (
                            150000000 ;serial number
                            10800 ; Refresh
                            3600 ; Retry
                            604800 ; Expire
                            38400 ) ; Negative Cache TTL


ywpadmin.com.           IN      NS      ns1.ywpadmin.com.
ywpadmin.com.           IN      NS      ns2.ywpadmin.com.
ns1.ywpadmin.com.       IN      A       10.0.0.200
ns2.ywpadmin.com.       IN      A       10.0.0.200
ywpadmin.com.           IN       A       40.142.31.34
www.ywpadmin.com.       IN       A       40.142.31.34
```

**Godaddy Configuration**

```
A     @    40.142.31.34
NS    @    ns03.domaincontrol.com   
NS    @    ns04.domaincontrol.com


------------ HOSTS -------------
Host    IP Addresses    
NS3    40.142.31.33 
NS4    40.142.31.33 
NS1    40.142.31.33 
NS2    40.142.31.33
```

Again I will be setting NS2 - NS4 up AFTER my configuration is solid.

I have tried updating the serial for this specific website multiple times and still I am having issues.   What else can I do as far as my server configuration or troubleshooting?  Is this a `GoDaddy` config issue or a `BIND` zone issue?  Does anything glaring look incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a long time gone, but a recent upvote on the question prompted me to answer with what helped me solve this issue.  I thought that it was enough to update the serial and to restart bind.  WRONG!  You need to flush `rndc` as well!  So when updating a zone file.  One should

1. Update the serial number
2. Flush RNDC name of host file you edited
3. Reload RNDC
4. Restart BIND

The flush and restart commands I user are:

```
sudo rndc flushname example.com.hosts 
sudo rndc reload
sudo service bind9 restart
```

This lets all the other DNS servers know that you've cleared the cache for that domain, it has a new serial and the content of the file has changed.  I've noticed that MOST DNS servers will pick up almost immediately -- But some can take up to 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The whois for ywpadmin.com shows that **ns03.domaincontrol.com** and **ns04.domaincontrol.com** are authoriative for this zone.

You should probably update the godaddy configuration so that **40.142.31.33** becomes authorative for **ywpadmin.com**. You typically use a glue record for ns1.ywpadmin.com -> 40.142.31.33, unless you already have another domain pointing to this host.